# Sort column by occurrence in shell

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to unix. I'm trying to sort a file by the occurence of values in a certain column in it:

```
IP    - - Website
1.1.1 - - stackoverflow.com
0.0.5 - - a.com 
1.1.1 - - google.com
```

expected result:

```
IP    - - Website
1.1.1 - - stackoverflow.com
0.0.5 - - a.com
```

I tried different methods:

- `sort -k1 | uniq -c` (didn't work because uniq checks the whole line, including websites)
- using `sort -u -t- -k1`

Can anyone help me, or at least tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

EDIT: I found a better way to do this: 
egrep -o '[[:digits:]]{1,3}.[[:digits:]]{1,3}.[[:digits:]]{1,3}'|sort -g | uniq -c | sort -gr (hope this will help someone one day)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. How often do you use 3-part dotted decimal IP addresses?  Do you want the data associated with the first row, the last row, or the 'maximum' row (last name sorted alphabetically) or the 'minimum' row or does it not matter which row.  What are the criteria for ordering 1.1.1 before 0.0.5?  Why is the header line still at the top (they're a pain to deal with, in general — which is why many Unix commands do not generate them).

Comment: Actually I gave only an example. What I want is to sort the IP from most occurrent to least occurrent in a  file that has the same structure of my example. Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an opportunity to [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It split line in two fields based in those `-` in the middle, and saves content in a hash to sort them later. In the hash, the key is the IP and the value is an array-ref with the counter of each IP appearance and the original line.

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
IP    - - Website
2.2.2 - - yahoo.es
1.1.1 - - in.google.com
0.0.5 - - a.com 
1.1.1 - - google.com
1.1.1 - - gmail.google.com
2.2.2 - - yahoo.com
```

And following `perl` command:

```
perl -lne '
    do { $header = $_; next } if $. == 1;
    my @f = split /\s+-\s+-\s+/;
    if ( ! exists $ips{ $f[0] } ) {
        $ips{ $f[0] } = [ 1, $_ ];
    }
    else {
        $ips{ $f[0] }[0] += 1;
    }
    END {
        printf qq|%s\n|, $header;
        for my $key ( sort { $ips{ $b }[0] <=> $ips{ $a }[0] } keys %ips ) {
            printf qq|%s\n|, $ips{ $key }[1];
        }
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
IP    - - Website
1.1.1 - - in.google.com
2.2.2 - - yahoo.es
0.0.5 - - a.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. This would do the work, but is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: @user2563597: Shorter in which terms?

Comment: By using simple commands such as sort, uniq (not writing a code)? Thanks

Comment: I used `perl` because it's more powerful to handle the increased complexity to work with a header or a counter of IPs. This is a one-liner that you can use as an alias or put it inside a `shell` script. If you don't like `perl` and want only `sort`, then my answer is no, I don't know how to do it only with `sort` + `uniq` combo, but it doesn't mean that is not posible. Simply my skill is not good enought.

Comment: You could simplify the Perl slightly by using `do { print; next; } if $. == 1;` and then omit printing `$header` later.  You could simplify the `if/else` into: `$ips{$f[0]} //= [ 0, $_ ]; $ips{$f[0]}[0]++;` (2 lines instead of 6).  You could use `-a` and `-F'\s+-\s+-\s+'` to auto-split into `@F`, with corresponding changes throughout.  But you did a nice job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right. I used `split()` because I thought that `perl` couldn't use a regular expression to split fields from `-F` switch, as `awk`. Good to know it. For `//` operator, perhaps better `||` because has same behaviour with references and is supported with older versions than `5.10`.

Answer (score 2):

It seem you are asking to remove any line with duplicate first fields. This can be achieved with the following `awk` one line:

```
$ awk '!a[$1]++' file
IP    - - Website
1.1.1 - - stackoverflow.com
0.0.5 - - a.com
```

Comment: This still doesn't do anything to sort by occurrence count.

Comment: @tripleee maybe you can explain better what the OP want as it's not clear to me, I described what I thought the OP wanted and the expected output matches...

Comment: Looks like @Birei understood it the same way I did. I agree the OP's example could be better.

Answer (score 0):

Simple shell solution...

```
egrep -o '^[0-9\.]+' myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score -1):

`uniq` can ignore the rest of lines after a specified number of characters with `-w`.

```
sort -r -k1 file | uniq -w5
```

`uniq -w` is not POSIX, but if you happen to be on a fairly up-to-date Linux, it should work.

Next I was informed that the first fields, unlike the vertically aligned example, are variable length. Should have known, it's an IP address, stupid! :) In that case I add 8 spaces after the IP address to compensate for the difference between the shortest (7) and longest (15) variants, tell uniq to disregard the 1st 15 chars, then compress the the remaining whitespaces to 1 again

```
sort -r -k1 file | sed 's/ /         /' | uniq -w15 | sed 's/  */ /'
```

No Perl.

Comment: I don't think this is portable to POSIX. Which systems support this?

Comment: Anyway, this doesn't solve the "sort by occurrences of the key field" requirement.

Comment: sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13 on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Actually the problem is with uniq -w5 : I don't the length of the IP, it's different each time